# Why bash history on my mac won't save?

Tags: terminal, bash

I have always used bash for work, and never had problems with it. Now, it does not save any command in history again. 
If I open a window terminal, try some commands, it acts like everything has worked fine and show me history using the arrow keys. But If I close the window (and that it is the time that it supposed to be save on the .bash_history file) and open another one, there are no signs of the last commands.

How can I find out what is going wrong? Or re-set everything from blank.

Comment: Could be your profile or rc file. What's in them?

Comment: What are the permissions and owner on your .bash_history? Mine are 600 and owned by me. Also, what's in $HIST_FILE?

Comment: @blm Permissions are right; printing the $HIST_FILE I found out about [.bash_sessions](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/) . Apparently there are problems when, at the end of a session, the OS save those file to the history file. I don't want to investigate anymore so I have simply put this in my home `.bash_sessions_disable` and know it return to the default behavior

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 45):

I did this:

Add a variable to `.bash_profile` file

`SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`

restart the terminal and after that it is working as I'd like. (It saved the commands after I closed the terminal)

P.S. I also use the `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTSIZE` variables

HISTSIZE is the number of lines or commands that are stored in memory in a history list while your bash session is ongoing.

HISTFILESIZE is the number of lines or commands that (a) are allowed in the history file at startup time of a session, and (b) are stored in the history file at the end of your bash session for use in future sessions.

Comment: Adding that one line works fine for me on El Capitan, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I would love to know why this works, too, if someone happens to know.  (History=0 would imply to my ignorant mind that all history will be lost, yet it seems to have the opposite effect.)

Comment: @Sysqa Is there some "in the middle" solution? The feature that "save and restore the bash command history independently for each restored terminal session" sounds like a nice feature some program might benefit from. Is there some way to have the benefits from the previous configuration and also the new one with some kind of configuration?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson, the comments in /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal give the answer:

"The default behavior arranges to save and restore the bash command history independently for each restored terminal session. It also merges commands into the global history for new sessions. Because of this it is recommended that you set HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE to larger values. You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 0."

My env currently has that var at "1", so I think they're saying "0" disables the per-session history, and "1" enables it.

Answer (score 10):

Starting in **OS X 10.11 El Capitan**, the system-installed script `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` coordinates with Terminal in order to save/restore separate command histories for each terminal restored for **Resume**.

Read the comments in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` for an explanation of how it manages per-terminal command histories and how to customize it.

If you customize `PROMPT_COMMAND` be sure to concatenate to the previous value so you don't wipe out the system-supplied command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }your_code_here"
```

If you install an `EXIT` signal handler with `trap` be sure to do something similar (or call shell_session_update from your handler if you can't figure out how to concatenate to the previous value—it's a little involved).

When you exit the shell, this code will save new commands to the terminal's history in `~/.bash_sessions`. To see if it encounters any problems, instead of closing the terminal exit the shell manually with `exit` (or Control-D). It logs progress messages. Note if it doesn't complete or if any sort of warning or error messages are displayed.

In general, `bashrc_Apple_Terminal` attempts to detect and disable per-session history if it looks like the user has performed any customizations that aren't compatible with it. It sounds like you may have found one it doesn't handle. Please consider filing a bug report with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: I haven't done any special configuration so I guess it's not the problem. Could you explain what the PROMPT_COMMAND does.

Comment: @loco.loop Do you mean “What is Bash’s PROMPT_COMMAND variable for?” or do you mean “What does `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` use PROMPT_COMMAND for?”? If the latter, I refer you to the code, which is documented in detail. Or, you should start another Q&A about that.

Comment: I mean what PROMPT_COMMAND for... @ChrisPage

Comment: @loco.loop I refer you to the Bash documentation, or suggest you start a Q&A about that.

Answer (score 10):

On a fresh install of Mac OS X (updated to 10.13.6), bash command history was not being saved. There were also no .bashrc or .bash_profile files. In this case, just adding an empty .bashrc file fixed it for me.

```
touch .bashrc
```

That's seems to be all you need...

Comment: seems to fix the issue on Mojave / 10.14, too :-)

Comment: Fixed for me as well, this should have more upvotes

Comment: What does this do? It is surprising that this would make a difference. It may indicate a bug somewhere that should be fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case there are others out there that have RVM (Ruby Version Manager) installed: Check to see if you have the following line in your `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files.

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

> It's probably RVM preventing the exit "hook" for bash_sessions to run.

That was the problem for me. Try commenting it out.

Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3g475b/el_capitan_terminal_bash_history_missing/)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with a newly installed osx Mojave. I checked my `~/.bash_history` file and saw this:

`$ ls -l ~/.bash_history 
-rw-------  1 root  staff  599 Jan  4 20:50 /Users/gilm/.bash_history`

Simply chowning it back to gilm solved the problem. I used:

`sudo chown gilm /Users/gilm/.bash_history`

and that solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. My history was lost when I switched the default shell from zsh to bash.

Answer (score 3):

You could also create a `.bash_logout` file with the following:

```
shell_session_update
```

[Sourced from GitHub comment](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3540#issuecomment-152824133)

Comment: Or, manually type `trap shell_session_update EXIT` once, and logout. There are clues in the `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` script that are too boring to include here.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was more hidden, yet easier to resolve.
By looking at the extended attribute of my `.bash_history` file and `.bash_sessions` content, I found out it had these attributes disallowing me to write despite the normal permissions:

```
$ ls -le .bash_history
-rw-r--r--@   1 XXX  staff  14484  2 Aug 17:04 .bash_history
 0: group:everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

The same if running `ls -lea .bash_sessions`.
The solution was "simply":

```
chmod -R -a# 0 .bash_sessions/ .bash_history
```