# Bash history not initially remembered with iterm2

Tags: bash, iterm, history

I've got an annoying problem with iterm2 not remembering my history when I close out a terminal window. I'm not sure if it might be my .bash_profile config or what.

Here is what is happening:

> ```
> 1) type in some commands
> 2) issue `history` command
> 3) commands are listed
> 4) close terminal window and open brand new terminal window
> 5) issue `history` command
> 6) commands from previous sessions are NOT listed
> 7) close terminal window and open brand new terminal window
> 6) issue `history` command
> 7) commands from very first session now appearing
> ```

Anyone know why the previous commands aren't showing up right away when a new window is opened and only after a second terminal window is opened?

**UPDATE:** <strike>Everything works as expected with the plain old terminal app.</strike>

**Update 2:** I have the shell integration feature installed

**Update 3:** It turns out the first update was incorrect. It is also flaky on Terminal. Sometimes it will work and other times it doesn't.

Comment: What happens when you exit the shell before closing the window?

Comment: If I type in the "exit" command, it works properly.

Comment: Try adding `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` to your `~/.bash_profile` file, quite the Terminal/iTerm2 App and reopen, test again.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that for now until I can get the problem resolved.

Comment: Editing `~/.bash_profile` with `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY` didn't do anything. The problem was `.bash_history` having permissions `-rw-------   root  staff` as set by `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. Little bit of `chown`ing solved it. Now history works with iTerm2.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out iterm was actually working in iterm. It just waits 5 seconds before saving to .bash_history when you close out of a shell without using the `exit` command. This 5 second delay is to give you time to command-z the session back open, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the double posting from [218731](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218731/why-bash-history-on-my-mac-wont-save).
For me the solution was more hidden, yet easier to resolve.
By looking at the extended attribute of my `.bash_history` file and `.bash_sessions` content, I found out it had these attributes disallowing me to write despite the normal permissions:

```
$ ls -le .bash_history
-rw-r--r--@   1 XXX  staff  14484  2 Aug 17:04 .bash_history
 0: group:everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

The same if running `ls -lea .bash_sessions`.
The solution was "simply":

```
chmod -R -a# 0 .bash_sessions/ .bash_history
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the iTerm issue raised in the question.