# Bash history is not remembered in Terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh

My Bash history is remembered when I connect to my Mac via SSH, use iTerm2 or launch `bash` in the built-in Terminal app (every command I typed in `bash` is saved) but is not when I just use the built-in Terminal app. I already tried resetting the profiles in Terminal. I also checked ownership and permissions of `.bash_history`. Later I also tried to delete this file. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50651/162962) didn't help either. My default shell definitely is `bash`.

Comment: Without further details, this could be a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50649/how-to-make-bash-terminal-app-remember-history-of-previous-sessions (linked on top as well), http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139807/what-does-update-terminal-cwd-do-in-the-terminal-of-os-x or one of the other similar questions here. Why don't you either try the suggestions in the answers to the linked questions or edit more details about your detailed setup and what you've already tried into the question?

Comment: @patrix Sorry about that. I already tried the suggestions in the question now linked above before posting this question. I added more information to my question.

Comment: Found a solution. I would have added it as an answer, if this question hadn't been locked. I had to create the following file ~/.bash_sessions_disable in order to disable behaviour introduced in El Capitan. http://superuser.com/questions/950403/bash-history-not-preserved-between-terminal-sessions-on-mac

Comment: The question’s not actually locked as far as I can tell. So I think you should be able to post your answer here (and if you do, I’ll upvote it, because while there’s already an answer for it a SuperUser, there isn’t one here at Ask Different yet).

Comment: Nothing suggested here seems to work on 10.15.5 with iTerm2 3.3.9. History is lost on close.

Comment: Editing `~/.bash_profile` with `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY` didn't do anything. The problem was `.bash_history` having permissions `-rw-------   root  staff` as set by `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. Little bit of `chown`ing solved it. Now history works with iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

Begin isolating the source of the problem by removing any customizations of Bash’s history. For example, any code that sets shell variables that begin with `HIST`, or uses `set -o` to set either the `history` or `histexpand` shell options.

The per-session command history code in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` attempts to maintain compatibility with Bash’s history variables, and tries to detect when the user is probably doing something it can’t be compatible with and disables the mechanism in that case (because the user is doing something arbitrary, like loading, saving or modifying the history). However, if you have scripts that run the `history` command, that code has no way of knowing in advance; you’ll need to either update your code to maintain compatibility with the new per-session command history, or disable the per-session history by setting `SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0` as described in the documentation in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`.

If you’re not customizing `HISTFILE`, `HISTTIMEFORMAT` or the `histappend` shell option, another thing to check is if your shell startup script(s) modify either `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable or the `EXIT` trap without concatenating the previous value to avoid wiping it out.

See the comments in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` for a description of how the mechanism works and how to customize or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/950403/bash-history-not-preserved-between-terminal-sessions-on-mac/985099#985099) from a similar question. El Capitan made some changes whereby it tries to do session-dependent history. You can likely fix your problem just by running `touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable` to create a flag file to disable this behaviour.